# queuing systems

Tags: queueing-theory

Suppose we have a $M/M/s$ queuing system :

> $L$  : is the mean number of the clients on the system
>
> $L_q$ : is the mean number of the clients on the queue
>
> $s$ : The number of the servers
>
> $n$ : The number of the clients at a given moment
>
> $P_n$ : The probability that we have exactly $n$ clients on the system

how can I prove the validity of this equation :

> $s-(L-L_q) = \sum_{n=0}^{s-1}(s-n).P_n$

Any ideas????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just figured out the answer :

We have

$ L=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n.P_n$

$ L_q= \sum_{n=s}^\infty (n-s).P_n$

so $L=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n-s+s).P_n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n-s).P_n+P_n.s$

$L=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n-s).P_n+\sum_{n=0}^\infty P_n.s =\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n-s).P_n+s.\sum_{n=0}^\infty P_n $

We have $\sum_{n=0}^\infty P_n = 1$ because $Pn$ represents a conditional probability.

$L=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n-s).P_n+s$

$L-L_q=(\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n-s).P_n) - (\sum_{n=s}^\infty (n-s).P_n) +s$

$L-L_q =(\sum_{n=0}^{s-1} (n-s).P_n)+(\sum_{n=s}^\infty (n-s).P_n) - (\sum_{n=s}^\infty (n-s).P_n) +s$

Wich gives us the result we wanted :

> $s-(L-L_q)=\sum_{n=0}^{s-1} (s-n).P_n$